# Correcting floating-point roundoff

Tags: floating-point, processing

I'm making a juggling game using Processing, and in the game, multiple balls fall down, and you keep them in the air by clicking on them. My problem is that whenever you click the ball, it goes higher than it had been before. I want to get rid of this problem, but I don't know how. My instructor said it was something about floating-point roundoff. Here's the code I have so far. It creates one ball, and it accelerates downward, and when it hits the walls it bounces back. My main problem is that as you continue playing the game, the ball goes out of sight. How can I fix this?

```java
int lives = 3;
float xPos = (int)random(0,500);
float yPos = (int)random(25,50);
int col1 = (int)random(0,255);
int col2 = (int)random(0,255);
int col3 = (int)random(0,255);
int diameter = 50;
float xSpeed = (int)random(1,4)*random(-1,1);
float ySpeed = 0;
boolean xSwitch = false;
boolean ySwitch = false;

void setup()
{
  size(750, 750);
  while(xSpeed == 0)
  {
    xSpeed = (int)random(1,4)*random(-1,1);
  }
}

void draw()
{
  if(xSwitch)
  {
    xSpeed = -xSpeed;
  }
  xPos += xSpeed;
  if(ySwitch)
  {
    ySpeed = -ySpeed;
  }
  yPos += ySpeed;
  background(255, 255, 255);
  ellipse(xPos, yPos, diameter, diameter);
  fill(col1, col2, col3);
  ySpeed += 0.05;
  xSwitch = false;
  ySwitch = false;
  if(xPos-25 < 0)
  {
    xSwitch = true;
  }
  if(xPos+25 > 750)
  {
    xSwitch = true;
  }
}

void mousePressed()
{
  float diffX = mouseX - xPos;
  float diffY = mouseY - yPos;
  float hyp = sqrt(diffX * diffX + diffY * diffY);
  if(hyp < 25)
  ySwitch = true;
}
```

If you need clarification of any part of the code, just comment below.

Comment: There are other problems with this game, like the fact that the lives aren't displayed, and there is only one ball, but I will ask other questions if need be.

Comment: you have a few `float <something> = (int) <something else>;`. It's not the cause of your problem, but don't int-cast if you're capturing something as float. That said, to check if it's rounding errors, change everything to `double` instead of `float` and see if it does the same. If so: it's your code, not the floating point data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your problem is that the ball goes off the screen, when the ball hits the top of the screen and is about to go higher, set the speed in the y-direction to 0. Try adding the below code to your draw() function.

```
if(yPos - 25 > 0)
{
  ySpeed = 0;
}
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: The problem isn't that the ball is going off the top of the screen: "My problem is that whenever you click the ball, it goes higher than it had been before."

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problem before. I don't know exactly why it happens, though. I decided to approach this from a physics perspective rather than a coding perspective, so of course one of the first things to do is look at the total energy (potential + kinetic). To do this, I included in your draw function the line

`println(0.5*(ySpeed*ySpeed + xSpeed*xSpeed) + g * (height-yPos));`

This prints out the kinetic energy (1/2 * m * v^2) added to the potential energy (m*g*h). This sum should be a constant (the number itself is arbitrary), since all forces acting on the ball are conservative. Note that the value for `m` is also arbitrary, so I left it as `1`. You'll notice that if you add the speed to the position, then the acceleration to the speed, the ball will gain total energy:

```
23.61237
23.61362
23.614872
23.61612
23.61737
23.61862
23.619871
```

while if you perform the actions in reverse (first add acceleration to speed, then add speed to position), the ball loses total energy:

```
24.257536
24.256285
24.255035
24.253786
24.252535
```

Interesting. Well, if adding it one way increases energy and adding it the other way decreases energy, then could we alternate between the two orders, like this?

```
  if(frameCount % 2 == 0){
    yPos += ySpeed;
    ySpeed += g;
  } else {
    ySpeed += g;
    yPos += ySpeed;
  }
```

This scheme (looking at whether the current iteration # is even or odd) gives energy as:

```
22.884935
22.886187
22.884935
22.886185
22.884935
22.886187
22.884935
```

Not bad. Again, I'm not sure why the order matters (it probably has something to do with symplectic vs non-symplectic numerical integration, but I'm not an expert in numerical techniques), but you asked for how to correct it so I think this will suffice :)

Side note: your code is peppered with "magic numbers" like 750 and 25. If you ever want to change your code, you'll have to go through and change every one of those manually-- not only tedious, but you'll probably miss some anyway. You already have variables in place for those values: 25 is `diameter/2` and 750 is `width` or `height`, so use them! It will make your code more robust for future changes.

Comment: Nailed it.  Think of what you're doing as solving a differential equation numerically.  You're using Euler's method with relatively coarse time steps, and each one increases the system's energy.  One way to fix it is by doing `yPos += ySpeed + g/2`.  Another is the integration you proposed, which does the right thing after every two iterations.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In any case, this phenomenon is most certainly _not_ due to floating-point truncation, what the instructor suggested. That may still exist for this code, but its effect will be in the last few decimal places for `float`s, orders of magnitude below the numbers in my answer.

Comment: @tmyklebu also, is your alternative just the familiar kinematics equation `dx = v0*t + 0.5*a*t^2` in the case where t=1?

Comment: Yeah, bingo.  (Another way to look at it is the limit of a bunch of forward Euler steps as the size of the bunch goes to infinity.)

Comment: @tmyklebu Hmm. I can't rationalize the 1/2 coefficient in that case. Perhaps a modified forward Euler?

Comment: Take `t = 1`.  (It's *also* the midpoint method applied to this problem, by the way.)

Comment: No, I meant standard Euler. Presumably you'd break ma = F into two first order equations, as the code above shows, where v' = F/m and x' = v. Applying standard Euler to both those equations in turn doesn't give a 1/2 factor, unless I'm missing something. However, I'd believe it coming from the midpoint method.

Comment: Yeah, forward Euler will increase your energy.  But the amount it increases energy over a given amount of time is proportional to the length of your time step.  Shorter and shorter steps mean a smaller global energy increase.  The limit as the time step goes to zero gives you the kinematic equation you gave above.